# Passing custom function to imported component in React

Tags: reactjs

This is a beginner react question as I am learning.

I have two files **hero.js** and **sidebar.js**.  There are two functions I have in hero.js that need to be accessed from buttons in sidebar.js (namely: onSave and onRestore).

How do I pass those functions down. I realize I probably need to do something like `this.onSave' but not sure how as still new to react.

**hero.js**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactFlow, {removeElements, addEdge,Controls, updateEdge, ReactFlowProvider,  useZoomPanHelper,} from "react-flow-renderer";
import Sidebar from './sidebar';
import localforage from 'localforage';



localforage.config({
  name: 'react-flow-docs',
  storeName: 'flows',
});

...


  const { transform } = useZoomPanHelper();

  const onSave = useCallback(() => {
    if (rfInstance) {
      const flow = rfInstance.toObject();
      localforage.setItem(flowKey, flow);
    }
  }, [rfInstance]);

  const onRestore = useCallback(() => {
    const restoreFlow = async () => {
      const flow = await localforage.getItem(flowKey);

      if (flow) {
        const [x = 0, y = 0] = flow.position;
        setElements(flow.elements || []);
        transform({ x, y, zoom: flow.zoom || 0 });
      }
    };

    restoreFlow();
  }, [setElements, transform]);



 return(
  <div className="hero_container" >
    <ReactFlowProvider>
      <div className='rowC'>
      <div className='reactflow-wrapper' style={{ height: 500, width: 1200 }} ref={reactFlowWrapper} >
          <ReactFlow
              elements={elements}
              onLoad={onLoad}
              onElementsRemove={onElementsRemove}
              onEdgeUpdate={onEdgeUpdate}
              onConnect={onConnect}
              onDragOver={onDragOver}
              onDrop={onDrop}
              deleteKeyCode={46} /* 'delete'-key */
          >
          <Controls />
          </ReactFlow>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
    </div>
    </ReactFlowProvider>
  </div>
 );
};
```

**sidebar.js**

```
mport React from 'react';


const Sidebar = () => {
  const onDragStart = (event, nodeType) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('application/reactflow', nodeType);
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  };

  return (
    <div className='side_controls'>
      <div className='add_node_area'>
        <h5>Add Nodes</h5>
        <div className="description">You can drag these nodes to the pane on the left.</div>
        <div className="react-flow__node-input" onDragStart={(event) => onDragStart(event, 'input')} draggable>
          Input Node
        </div>
        <div className="react-flow__node-default" onDragStart={(event) => onDragStart(event, 'default')} draggable>
          Default Node
        </div>
        <div className="react-flow__node-output" onDragStart={(event) => onDragStart(event, 'output')} draggable>
          Output Node
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='save_restore_buttons'>
        <button onClick={onSave}>save</button>
        <button onClick={onRestore}>restore</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: You have imported `sidebar.js` inside `hero.js` but you haven't included the code where you used this component ?

Comment: @UmerAbbas I have added the render component where I use <sidebar />

Comment: You can throw needed functions  throught props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access these functions inside `Sidebar` component by passing them as props

```
<Sidebar onSave={onSave} onRestore={onRestore} />
```

And in sidebar.js

```
const Sidebar = (props) => {
    const {onSave, onRestore} = props;
```

Comment: is this the same as ` <button onClick={this.props.onSave}>save</button>`

Comment: @user1357015, nope, in functional component you haven't props in  `this`

Comment: for class components yes, but in functional component `this` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it in as props from `hero.js`

```
<Sidebar onSave={onSave} onRestore={onRestore} />
```

then use it in `sidebar.js`

```
const Sidebar = (props) => {
   const {onSave, onRestore} = props;

   return (
      <div className='save_restore_buttons'>
        <button onClick={onSave}>save</button>
        <button onClick={onRestore}>restore</button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass your functions as `props` to the Component that you want to use in there, and then in the destination component, you can use those functions with `props.[prop-name]`
For more information, you can read [this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

**hero.js**

```
<Sidebar onSave={onSave}  onRestore={onRestore}/>
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
<div className='save_restore_buttons'>
     <button onClick={props.onSave}>save</button>
     <button onClick={props.onRestore}>restore</button>
</div>
```